# Why i can not connect to admin panel/client by domain?

Tags: ejabberd

I try install ejabberd on my server. Then i install it, i edit ejabberd.yml file. Add domain in hosts section. When I try to connect to the admin panel by domain, it just doesn’t connect. But if I connect by ip everything works. What should I do ? Where to look ?

Answer (score 0):

> it just doesn’t connect

Does ejabberd show the connection attempt in the ejabberd log file?

If yes: I guess the web browser also requests you an admin account and password. You will have to register a new account in ejabberd, grant it admin rights in the configuration file, and restart ejabberd.

If nothing shown in the log file, then maybe your web browser doesn't know how to connect to ejabberd. Maybe you need to setup DNS.

Comment: The log file is not empty. I can’t connect by domain. Connected only by ip